# How to save R datasets(eg: datasets from libraries like MASS, ISLR, etc.,) to a csv file

Tags: r, statistics, dataset, export-to-csv

How to extract the datasets that are provided in r libraries into csv files. Faced this issue when trying to implement R related data analysis programs in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can make sure the data is loaded from the package with `data()` and then write it out with `write.csv`

```
data(Boston, package = "MASS")
write.csv(Boston, "Boston.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the "Boston" dataset that is available in the "MASS" library in R to a csv, and if the library() function is already called in your code like this:

```
library(MASS)
```

then, simply use the below line:

```
write.csv(Boston, "Boston.csv")
```